# Difficulty setting up .screenrc file: [screen is terminating]

Tags: gnu-screen

I rely on screen extensively for development and server management.  In the rare event that a server reboots, I have to rebuild my screen sessions manually, and I've known about the `.screenrc` method of automating the startup of a screen session, but I've never been able to get it to work. I've tried testing with very simple commands, and these work, but they create two identical windows inside of a single screen session.  The more complex commands - which I actually need - cause screen to terminate.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 server, with `Screen version 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20`

My `.screenrc` file is simple, which is a modified version of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/386122).

```
# don't display the copyright page
startup_message off

# increase scrollback buffer size
defscrollback 10000

# create windows
screen -t test1 ls $HOME/
```

Yet, when I `source .screenrc` or even just type `screen` in my terminal, I get the following output, suggesting my version of screen has no idea what I'm asking it to do:

```
~$ source .screenrc
startup_message: command not found
defscrollback: command not found
[screen is terminating]
```

When I use screen, I manually set it up for the following tasks every time:

- tail a specific service in journalctl
- Open Python's IDLE in a virtual environment
- tail a log file in a specific directory
- run a `docker exec` command to open a shell in a container

When I modify `.screenrc` to tail a specific service file with the following .screenrc entry...

`screen -t journalctl journalctl -u  my-service-name.service -b -n 100 -f`

Screen will run, but it creates two windows inside the screen session, both of which are running the journalctl command above.

Other issues I'm having with setting up the above mentioned tasks:

- Trying to activate my python virtual environment within screen gives me an error message:

  The command in screenrc is: `screen -t python3 . $HOME/my-project-dir/venv/bin/activate`

  The error from screen is:  `Cannot exec '.': Permission denied`
- Trying to get screen to run the `docker exec` command just causes screen to terminate with no output.

Comment: The .screenrc is not meant to be sourced. It's read automatically by screen on startup.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. That is helpful. I misunderstood [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/194597/how-to-reload-screenrc-without-restarting-screen) regarding loading screenrc settings. I also found `screen -L` which logs the output from each window to a file. Now the only issue I'm having is using source to activate my Python virtualenv via screenrc.